# How do you link cells to a dynamically created userform checkbox.

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to figure out for over a week on this problem and still haven't figure it out and our deadline is in 3 days. So we can see below that I dynamically created this userform checkboxes based on a specific range of cells.

However, whenever the checkbox is true or list of checkboxes are true, it finds the caption name of that checkbox in the sheet and offsets by 4 rows; the values from the new cell/ cells are used to then find the average in a new cell. I have watched a lot of videos and blogs which didn't seem to fit the problem.

I'm more accustom to C/C++, Python. VBA excel is a bit new to me and troubleshooting a bit difficult.

**********************************Code1*************************************

```
Private Sub AddCheckbox()

 Dim Rows As Integer
 Dim toppart As Integer
 Dim Opt As Variant
 Dim x As Integer

 On Error Resume Next
 toppart = 20

UpdateRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(ActiveSheet.Range("C:ZU"))

For x = 3 To UpdateRow

    Set Opt = Te.Controls.Add("Forms.CheckBox.1", "CheckBox" & x, True)

   Opt.Caption = ActiveSheet.Cells(3, x).Value


    Opt.Width = 70
    Opt.Height = 18
    Opt.Left = 18

    Opt.Top = toppart
    toppart = toppart + 20
    Next

End Sub
```

*******************************Code2****************************************

```
Private Sub Average()

Dim Ctrl As Object
Dim R As Range
Dim key As Integer

For Each Ctrl In Te.Controls
    If TypeName(Ctrl) = "Checkbox" Then
        If Ctrl.Value = True Then

         key = ActiveSheet.Cells(3, x).Value
        Set R = Range("C3:CU3").Find(What:=key)
    End If
        End If
Next


End Sub
```

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: `On Error Resume Next` is probably not helping. Or did you mean to add `On Error GoTo 0` after the `UpdateRow` assignment?

Comment: On Error Resume Next, that part of the code actually works, i tried it out. Code 2 or the 2nd function is the problem, I'm trying to dynamically link the cells to the checkboxes that were also created dynamically.

Comment: Did you try breakpoints (F9) and stepping through (F8)?

Comment: Where it's giving the problem?

Comment: @Mat'sMug  i did try to F9 and F8 stop working at find function

Answer (score 0):

You can create check boxes with this:

```
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long
Dim shp As Shape
Dim rng As Range

Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Plan1")
lRow = sh.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For Each rng In sh.Range("C3:C" & lRow)
    Set shp = sh.Shapes.AddFormControl(xlCheckBox, Left:=rng.Offset(0, -1).Left, Top:=rng.Offset(0, -1).Top, Width:=70, Height:=18)
    shp.Select
    With Selection
        .Caption = rng.Value
    End With
Next rng
```

And then, check each check boxes like that:

```
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim shp As Shape
Dim key As String
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim FindRange As Range
Dim lRow As Long

Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Plan1")
lRow = sh.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set rng1 = sh.Range("C3:C" & lRow)

For Each shp In sh.Shapes
    If InStr(shp.Name, "Check Box") <> 0 Then 'If is a check box then

        If shp.ControlFormat.Value = 1 Then 'If checkbox is checked

            key = shp.AlternativeText 'Get the name of the checkbox

            Set FindRange = rng1.Find(What:=key, LookIn:=xlValues) 'search in the rng1 that name

            If Not FindRange Is Nothing Then 'If found, then
                Set rng2 = FindRange.Offset(0, 4) 'save the range with 4 columns offset in rng2

                'do something

            End If

        End If

    End If
Next shp
```

Don't forget to change the names of the Worksheets.

Comment: The first code has an error with respect to the caption. I'm trying to alter the 2nd code to adjust to my first code.